# performance of real time chatting techniques

Tags: node.js, performance, chat, real-time

I assigned myself with the task of implementing the chat app (1:1) for my curriculum.Among the various options I used SSE for real time chats.From the example projects I am able to implement the non persistent chat  between two clients.In every examples they uses js `object` and `array` to store the `res` object and by iterating them they sent events to particular user.But when implementing the real time chat app the users may increase dramatically So it is not good to exhaust server resources.

**I found the some of the other ways to achieve same
functionality but not sure about the performance**

1. SSE+setInterval

   - I used `redis` Queue to push offline messages to the user.
   - when the user establishes the connection push all the unread chats to client.
   - This process happens immediately when client establishes connection with server.

     1. I faced some problem here, as I have no way of triggering the messages in real time(when both users online).
     2. So I used `setInterval` with time interval of 1 second for real time communication and write a callback function to check if the Queue is empty else pop message from Queue and sent to user as an event.
     3. Will the above solutions affect performance ? Because I am calling the function for each connected user x 1 second interval.
2. Long polling

   - In long polling how can I find if there is new message for user and complete the request ?
   - Still here `setInterval` should be used in server side but what about performance?
3. Websockets

   - In `websockets` we have an unique id to find the client in the pool of clients, so we can forward message to particular user when event occurs.
   - Still `websockets` uses some ping pong mechanism to make connection persistent but resource utilization is very small as they are network calls with comparatively small data and handled asynchronously so no wastage in server resource.

**Questions**

1. How to trigger `res.write` only when the new message arrives to particular user?
2. Does SSE+setInterval or longpolling+setInterval degrades performance when user increases?
3. Else is there any design pattern to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use websocket.
It's fast, convinient and simple.
To send message in realtime when both users are logged, find second user by id in users Array or Map and send received message to his websocket.
If you have buffered messages for disconnected user (in memory/database/redis) check it when user connects and send if it exists.

Comment: I know websockets solves my problem easily, I want to give a try  to other techniques which helps me to gain more knowledge about how to make the stuff work when there is no dedicated technology available but some people downvoted it,I dont know why?